# Load entire page with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to load an entire HTML page (include the head which may have CSS/JS, etc...) into view using jQuery? I'd like to basically load a new page without refreshing the browser.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: I assume you can, but the way to go in that case is to use a helper library like PJAX.

Comment: Yeah, I thought about an iframe but this seems more like a mask... Was hoping I could actually just replace all content of the page at runtime... on the client side.

Comment: @Ibrahim, but this wouldn't load the JS functions, etc... that may exist on the loaded page

Comment: @Andrew - when you request a page using ajax, all js is also loaded

Comment: Why of course you can. It just may not end up the way you like it... Bare in mind: replacing existing `<script>` tags won't remove the JavaScript from the current session.

Comment: @Rajesh, so how could I replace the page with Ajax?

Comment: I need a pretty robust solution that could work with any page... and not knowing the contents. I'm thinking an iFrame like @Lix suggested is the best course... thoughts?

Comment: The best approach will be to use Divs to load page contents

Comment: Can I ask why you would want to do this?

Comment: @Rajesh, but what about head content?

Comment: @Joe Buckle - I have a CMS that generates pages for SEO purposes. The content is readable but not designed. At run time, I want to replace the content with the nicely designed content.

Comment: If you are not refreshing, then you cannot reload head without some dirty js code

Comment: @Rajesh - that's what I thought

Comment: but the js will be added wherever you load the dynamic content. So, the handlers in the js have to be written carefully

Comment: In that case, I'd rather suggest checking the user's navigator on server-side. If you detect a search engine, deliver the SEO page. Otherwise simply feed the user's browser with the designed website. Seems a lot safer to me...

Comment: This doesn't seem right to me. Replacing an entire HTML page. Usually we just replace elements.

Comment: ok, thanks for all the responses. I'm going to review my concept.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you looking for a single page application? If you look into a framework like AngularJS it will give you the control you need, although it's not that common to replace the *whole* page, just the stuff that needs to be changed (analog to a server side mvc solution with partial views or a master view).

You can always load JS on the fly if you need to.